# R Shiny disable selected checkbokGroupInput

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I want to disable preselected checkboxGroupInputs: i.e:

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId  = "ID", 
                   label    = NULL, 
                   choices  = checkbox_list_items, 
                   selected = pre_select_these_items)
```

Then I want to have the items `pre_select_these_items` to be disabled, i.e. something like this:

```
checkboxGroupInput(inputId  = "ID", 
                   label    = NULL, 
                   choices  = checkbox_list_items, 
                   selected = pre_select_these_items,
                   disable  = pre_select_these_items)
```

This `disable` option does not exists.

Indeed there are similar questions like this, but most of them ask how to disable on an event, what I need is before any event occurs.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: so you want check boxes that cant be checked?

Comment: Yes, but only for the preselected ones. Hence, if the list of items are 10, then 3, should be pre-checked and also cannot be checked, the remaining 7 should be free and could be checked. Is this clear?

Comment: How does work exactly? I see that I need to pass it a list of names and values, and in the values some HTML code. Could you please provide an example or link to an example?